# Handling Exceptions from an Async WCF Web Service call

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I have a third-party web-service reference which has a web method *AddDocument*.
Our application called this method synchronously before but I need to implement asynchronous call to this method now.

I have reconfigured web-service reference in my project by checking "Generate Asynchronous Operations" checkbox.
Now I have a *BeginAddDocument* method available, which I am calling as:

```
AsyncCallback callback = ProcessAsyncResult;
object asyncState = "TestAsyncState";
srv.BeginAddDocument(Credentials, document, callback, asyncState);
```

And I have prepared a stab for a callback method:

```
public void ProcessAsyncResult(IAsyncResult result)
{
}
```

Sometimes the web-service returns errors.
They can be easily catched and handled while calling method synchronously.

But unfortunately I cannot find any clear answers how to catch exceptions using asynchronous approach, keeping in mind that I cannot modify the web-service itself.

IAsyncResult in the callback method seems to be the same regardless of the operation result - be it a success or an exception.

Is it possible at all to catch exceptions from a web service using asynchronous approach, and if it is, what is the best way to make it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually with the "BeginYYYxxx" ASync pattern, there is a matching "EndYYYxxx" method that you call. Assuming they've written the third-party service using this pattern, you should be able to just get the resulting object from the `AsyncState` of IAsyncResult. The [documentation for `IAsyncResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may be of use to you.

Without seeing the documentation for the service, this is my best guess:

```
AsyncCallback callback = ProcessAsyncResult;
object asyncState = "TestAsyncState";
srv.BeginAddDocument(Credentials, document, callback, asyncState);


public void ProcessAsyncResult(IAsyncResult result)
{
    TypeThatsrvIs s = (TypeThatsrvIs)result.AsyncState;

    //"s" will be the same srv object that you called BeginAddDocument on.
    //It "should" contain the web-service result.
    s = s.EndAddDocument(result);

    /*
    Do stuff with that resulting object.
    */

}
```

Hope that helps.

Edit: You may actually have to pass the `srv` object as the AsyncState in order to get it back in the `ProcessAsyncResult` method:

```
AsyncCallback callback = ProcessAsyncResult;
object asyncState = srv;
srv.BeginAddDocument(Credentials, document, callback, asyncState);
```

Comment: Brandon, thank you a lot for your quick and informative reply.
Yes, indeed, seems like invoking EndAddDocument on the same service object with IAsyncResult parameter resolved the problem by throwing exactly the same exception which was usually received in synchronous call before.
Thank you once more for your expertise!

Answer (score 0):

As Brandon suggested in his reply, the solution was really simple, and was not clear for me only due to my lack of experience in asynchronous web method call pattern. The resulting code of the callback method is as follows:

```
public void ProcessAsyncResult(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        ServiceSoapClient srv = result.AsyncState as ServiceSoapClient;
        if (srv == null) return;
        try
        {
            srv.EndAddDocument(result);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            //your code to handle exception here
        }
    }
```